# Show pdf only to authenticated users

Tags: python, html, pdf, permissions, pylons

I'm building a web site from the old one and i need to show a lot of .pdf files.

I need users to get authenficated before the can't see any of my .pdf but i don't know how (and i can't put my pdf in my database).

I'm using Pylons with Python.

Thank for you help.

If you have any question, ask me! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my stab at how to do it in Pylons. I haven't tested this but there should be enough links to get you going.

1. Enable X-SendFile on your HTTP server (as Paul said, the implementation depends on the server): Apache [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/), Nginx [equivalent](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxXSendfile)
2. Put the PDFs **outside** the /public directory in your Pylons install (I'd suggest a directory at the same level as your Pylons directory)
3. Add some kind of Authentication and Authorization to your site. [Here](http://gustavonarea.net/blog/posts/repoze-auth/) is a good article on how you use [repoze.who](http://docs.repoze.org/who/1.0/) (Authentication) and [repoze.what](http://what.repoze.org/docs/1.0/) (Authorization)
4. Create a route and controller to handle the request for your PDF, this is like any other route and controller. (ie a route of /pdfs/{filename}.pdf)
5. If everything is authorized and authenticated properly you can create the right headers for the x-sendfile (or equivalent) you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the X-Sendfile header to send those files. Precise details will depend on which Http server you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Paul's suggestion of X-Sendfile is excellent - this is truly a great way to deal with actually getting the document back to the user. (+1 for Paul :)

As for the front end, do something like this:

1. Store your pdfs somewhere not accessible by the web (say /secure)
2. Offer a URL that looks like /unsecure/filename.pdf
3. Have your HTTP server (if it's Apache, see Mod Rewrite) convert that link into /normal/php/path/authenticator.php?file=filename.pdf
4. authenticator.php confirms that the file exists, that the user is legit (i.e. via a cookie), and then uses X-Sendfile to return the PDF.

Comment: For Pylons you would do all this is the routing/controllers, obviously :)

Comment: @Ben - yeah, if you actually know how to do that in Pylons, I'll upvote ya... I'm not a Python or Pylons programmer :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe filename with md5 key will be enough?

48cd84ab06b0a18f3b6e024703cfd246-myfilename.pdf

You can use filename and datetime.now to generate md5 key.